# Testing async methods in jest gets mock resolved values mixed up

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, jestjs

I'm writing some jest tests to test an async method. If I run each test individually, it works! However, when I run the whole suite, they fail. The mock values from one test end up in another test because I suspect that jest is not waiting for one to finish before moving onto another.

```
describe('testing method', () => {
test('test case 1', async () => {
dependentService.method.mockResolvedValueOnce(mockResult1);
expect(await testSubject(input)).toBe(expectedResult);
});
 test('test case 2', async () => {
dependentService.method.mockResolvedValueOnce(mockResult2);
expect(await testSubject(input)).toBe(expectedResult);
});
});
```

In the above sample code snippet, the mockResult2 is used in the test case 1, instead of mockResult1. How do I get this to behave as I expect?

Comment: How did you define `mockResult1` and `mockResult2`? What does `testSubject` do? Jest should run all tests in the same suite sequentially, even if they're asynchronous, so if it's not waiting properly that would indicate something causes `testSubject` to fulfill before it's actually finished. Can you post a [mcve] please that we can run ourselves?

Comment: maybe restoring mocks after each test case can help. `restoreMocks`, `resetMocks` you can find them in jest config

Comment: Can you include the content of your `testSubject` function in the question?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  The mocked implementation of a method is different in the tests and Jest mixes them up, probably because it is interleaving the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Changing up the `expect` syntax will solve the problem.

```
await expect(testSubject(input)).resolves.toBe(expectedResult)
```

The `toBe` part of that line is mandatory - without it jest wont wait for the promise to resolve and the framework will mix up promises across tests.

Comment: Using `expect(await …)` works just the same

Comment: Is there any difference between using ‘await expect(…’ and ‘expect(await …’ ?

Answer (score 0):

Jest executes all testcases in parallel but you can execute serially by adding this flag

```
jest --runInBand
```